# Have multiple elements under different divs disappear on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have `2` grid divs, one with images and the other with a list of names. Each element within each of the divs corresponds to another within the other div (eg. `.image-1` corresponds with `.name-1`).

When you hover over one of the elements, I want that element AND the corresponding element in the other div to both disappear.

For example, when you hover over `"Name 1"`, I want that and the corresponding `image` to both disappear. Here's my general `html` setup:

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="picture-grid grid">
      <div class="grid-box image-1">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/image1.png" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-box image-2">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/image2.png" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-box image-3">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/image3.png" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-box image-4">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/image4.png" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-box image-5">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/image5.png" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="names-grid grid">
      <div class="grid-box name-1"><a href="#">Name 1</a></div>
      <div class="grid-box name-2"><a href="#">Name 2</a></div>
      <div class="grid-box name-3"><a href="#">Name 3</a></div>
      <div class="grid-box name-4"><a href="#">Name 4</a></div>
      <div class="grid-box name-5"><a href="#">Name 5</a></div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

I'm sorry, I've been stuck on this for hours and would love some help! Here's a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/8egpf1j3/

Comment: You could add a class, like one, two, and so on.

Comment: Are you open to `JQuery` solution? I see the library is included on the `jsfiddle`.

Comment: @Shidersz yes I am open to any solution!

Comment: @Jodast I've tried adding the same class to both elements and use :hover {opacity: 0;}. but it only effects one item at a time, not both at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution using `JQuery` is to add `data-*` attributes to the `HTML` markup. In this approach we going to add a `data-target` attribute that will hold the `class` of the related element that should be hidden (with `opacity: 0`) when the current element is hovered. You can use [JQuery.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) to work with `data-*` attributes. Check the next simplified example, from where I hope you can understand the underlying idea.

```js
$(".grid-box").hover(
    // Handler for hover-in.
    function()
    {
        $(this).css("opacity", 0);
        $($(this).data("target")).css("opacity", 0);
    },
    // Handler for hover-out.
    function()
    {
        $(this).css("opacity", 1);
        $($(this).data("target")).css("opacity", 1);
    }
);
```

```css
.grid-box {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
 
   <div class="picture-grid grid">
     <div class="grid-box image-1" data-target=".name-1">
       <a href="#">IMAGE 1</a>
     </div>
     <div class="grid-box image-2" data-target=".name-2">
       <a href="#">IMAGE 2</a>
     </div>
     <div class="grid-box image-3" data-target=".name-3">
       <a href="#">IMAGE 3</a>
     </div>
     <div class="grid-box image-4" data-target=".name-4">
       <a href="#">IMAGE 4</a>
     </div>
   </div>
   
   <hr>

   <div class="names-grid grid">
     <div class="grid-box name-1" data-target=".image-1">
       <a href="#">Name 1</a>
     </div>
     <div class="grid-box name-2" data-target=".image-2">
       <a href="#">Name 2</a>
     </div>
     <div class="grid-box name-3" data-target=".image-3">
       <a href="#">Name 3</a>
     </div>
     <div class="grid-box name-4" data-target=".image-4">
       <a href="#">Name 4</a>
     </div>
   </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way, I suppose number of images and names is the same, and they are in the same order. Means image number one is first in its div, and name number one is first in its div.

```
//getting all pictures by <a> tag
var pictures = document.querySelector(".picture-grid").querySelectorAll("a"); 
//getting all names by <a> tag
var names = document.querySelector(".names-grid").querySelectorAll("a");

//attach reaction to "hover" event to all pictures and names
for (var i = 0; i < pictures.length; i++){
  pictures[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", hide.bind(i));
  names[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", hide.bind(i));
}

//run function on "hover" event, i = index of chosen image/name
function hide (){
  var i = this;
  pictures[i].style.opacity = 0;
  names[i].style.opacity = 0;
}
```